# Select Users That Exist Only On One Specific List (phplist)

Tags: mysql, sql, phplist

I need a MYSQL query to identify all subscribers on phplist that are only on one list (with list ID 126).

There are two tables involved.

1.)  phplist_user_user
2.)  phplist_listuser

phplist_listuser has two fields called 'userid' and 'listid' that are of concern.
phplist_user_user has a 'userid' as well which is the key to the user fields in this table.

We want a query that will list:

all details of users (from phplist_user_user)
that have an entry on phplist_listuser for the listid 126
AND only are on listid 126 so they should only have entries for listid 126 in phplist_listuser, if they have any other list then they should not be included.

So to re-word the above we want: 
User details of users that are on listid 126 but not on any other list.

here is example of tables

```
phplist_listuser
userid listid

1      126

1      32

1      51 

2      126

3      126

4      126

5      126

5      127

6      128
```

On this query I would only want the user details from phplist_user_user that have the IDs 2, 3, 4 and not the others because they are either not on 126 or on 126 but also on other lists.

Can anyone help me here?

```
SELECT * FROM phplist_listuser
WHERE listid <=> 126;
```

The above works to get every userID that is on list 126, but I now need to be able to check that the user is not on any other lists, and then pull the full info from phplist_user_user.

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is obvious but I put some work and research into it and can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS:

```
select * 
from phplist_user_user uu
where exists (select * from phplist_listuser lu where lu.listid = 126 and lu.userid = uu.userid)
and not exists (select * from phplist_listuser lu where lu.listid <> 126 and lu.userid = uu.userid);
```

EDIT: Another way is to use an IN clause on all listusers where the only listid is 126:

```
select * 
from phplist_user_user
where userid in
(
  select lu.userid 
  from phplist_listuser lu
  group by lu.userid
  having min(lu.listid) = 126 and max(lu.listid) = 126
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a [feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) that allows you to use non-aggregate columns in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT u.*,lu.listid FROM phplist_user_user u
JOIN phplist_listuser lu USING (userid)
GROUP BY u.userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT lu.listid)=1 AND lu.listid=126;
```

This is just to show that this can be done in MySQL without using subselect.